# Error after updating to Rails 3.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just upgraded to Rails 3.0.5 and installed the updated gems.

When I run the command "rails -v" to check what version I'm on.. I get the following error:

> Could not find activesupport-3.0.4

Any idea of what could be causing this? When I run `gem list` I get the following versions for ActiveSupport:

> activesupport (3.0.5, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.4.4)"

Comment: What version of Rails is listed in `gem list`? What does your Gemfile look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your Gemfile, change your version of Rails to 3.0.5 and then run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to do bundle update to get everything fully up to date.

Answer (score 2):

It may be the Gemfile.lock specifies 3.0.4. Perhaps remove that file (rm Gemfile.lock)?